# Power bi sql live data on demand

Tags: powerbi

Is there any way to add datepicker to report and based on datepicker value can we get the live data from sql server on demand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with Direct Query connection to your table and date field from it (or from calendar table) in a slicer?

Comment: I need to take FromDate add ToDate from user and need to pull data on click of Button dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the date filters [in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters) of your report. This means to add a query string parameter like this:

```
?filter=SalesData/SaleDate ge 2018-01-01 and SalesData/SaleDate se 2018-12-31
```

To filter the `SalesData` table on `SaleDate` field to show only data for 2018.

You can create one helper report with a date table and slicer, which will generate the actual link to your report. To do this, create a new calendar table (from `Modeling` -> `New Table`) with the dates you want, e.g.:

```
Date = CALENDAR (DATE(2000;1;1); DATE(2030;12;31))
```

Create a new measure to calculate the filtered URL:

```
ReportUrl = "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/xxxxx/reports/xxxxx?filter=SalesData/SaleDate ge " &
    FORMAT(MIN('Date'[Date]); "yyyy-MM-dd") & 
    " and SalesData/SaleDate se " & FORMAT(MAX('Date'[Date]); "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Do not forget to replace `xxxxx` with actual group and report IDs. Make sure the measure data category is `Web URL` [to make it a hyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-hyperlinks-in-tables). Show it somewhere, where the user can click on it:

[image]